# PHP rename() args don't work if I prefix with a "/"

Tags: php, apache

This works:

```
rename("box/". $picture , "box/tmp/". $picture);
```

This does not:

```
rename("/box/". $picture , "/box/tmp/". $picture);
```

results in a file/directory not found error.

This may seem menial, however I have a problem with my code and the underlying problem to this may be the root cause of another problem of mine.

Thanks

Comment: `rename("box/")` is a path relative to the current directory.  `rename("/box/")` is an absolute path relative to the root directory.  These are very different things.  This example may help illustrate the difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Unix_style

Comment: Just curious why did you think that adding some arbitrary character before the directory name shouldn't break everything?

Comment: I thought that it was optional since in a lot of my html all of my scripts included are prefixed with a '/'. Figured it was proper coding to designate a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rename` works with file system paths and is not based on the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` unless you have a really odd setup then `/box` (or `c:\box` on a windows system) isnt going to exist and even if it did unless you wen out of your way the webserver wouldnt have permission to write to it.

What you probably want is something more like this:

```
rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/box/' . $picture, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/box/tmp/' . $picture);
```

Comment: Shenanigans!... you owe me coke.

Answer (score 0):

unless you have a directory named "box" off the root of your filesystem, your second example won't work. The leading slash means "at the root of the filesystem."